# Stretching for kicks

Tags: training, stretching, flexibility

I'm 42 years old and have never been very flexible. I do Tae Kwon do and need to improve my kicks. Any good leg/hip stretches?  I've been working hard on it for last year but not much improvement. Thanks

Comment: Also, I recommend anyone training high kicking martial arts watch some of Bill "Superfoot" Wallace's videos on stretching. Many clips of his videos are available on Youtube. This is one of my favorites: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxokaEvKnD8

Comment: See also [How do I increase flexibility to achieve a full split?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-do-i-increase-flexibility-to-achieve-a-full-split) [Good exercises for higher side kicks?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/93/good-exercises-for-higher-side-kicks) [How do I increase hip flexibility for round kicks?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-do-i-increase-hip-flexibility-for-round-kicks) [The 180 degree leg split](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/the-180-degree-leg-split)

Comment: @TheWudangKid I disagree, I think leg/hip stretches that help the best with kicking is pretty specific. My lack of hip flexibility is the reason I stopped doing Sanshou.